# Vue.js - Sorting a list in descending order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to display a sorted list using the value I get from my **DataObject**:

```
<div class="recommendation" v-for="l in list" :key="`_${l.id}`">
```

My **list** is not currently ordered:

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      list: []
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let self = this;
    backend.matches().then(function(resp) {
      self.list = resp.data.listings;
    });
  },
  computed: {
    
  }
};
```

I want to order my list with my **l.weight** value in descending order.

What would be the best approach to order my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `sort` method :

```
    backend.matches().then(function(resp) {
      self.list = resp.data.listings;
      self.list.sort((a,b)=>a.weight<b.weight?1:-1) 
    });
```